# Uppercase each first letter of words with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, pcre

So I have some sentences I am inserting into a database with some auto-correction processes. The following sentence:

```
$sentence = "Is this dog your's because it can't be mine";
```

And the following code to capitalize each word but make sure it doesn't capitalize contractions (eg. n't):

```
str_replace(
    "'S", "'s", preg_replace(
       "/(\w+)n'T?/", "$1n't", (
           preg_replace(
              "/\b[a-z]/e", 
              'strtoupper("$0")', 
              ucwords($sentence)
           )
       )
   )
);
```

When echoing, the result is as follows:

```
Is This Dog Your's Because It Can't Be Mine
```

This is what I want it to do, however, what it inputs into my MySQL database is:

```
Is This Dog Your's Because It Can'T Be Mine
```

I have no idea why this is happening... I am assuming that I messed something up somewhere.

Comment: *"I have no idea why this is happening..."* - well see here: `'strtoupper("$0")'`, it happens because you wrote so. and don't use the `/e` modifier (eval) any longer. instead use a callback. That modifier is deprecated now and it has serious security implications, so this is really a good meant suggestion to improve your code.

Comment: You're missing like three closing parentheses.

Comment: @ironcito - Sorry, my example line doesn't have the ))) but it is in the actual code I'm using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should of course use [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/ucwords), but this is how you would do it with a regular expression:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\s|^)[a-z]/', function($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[0]);
}, $sentence);
```

It makes sure that each lower case character is preceded by a space (or start of the sentence)  by using a lookbehind [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), before it's changed to upper case.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords) instead ([Demo](https://eval.in/42931)):

```
$sentence = "Is this dog your's because it can't be mine";

echo ucwords($sentence); # Prints "Is This Dog Your's Because It Can't Be Mine"
```

Comment: That does work... however, the code had to be able to deal with things like names (eg. O'Reilly) and numbers (eg. 2nd).

Comment: @SlothLordKyle: Better write that in your question otherwise nobody knows. I also edited your title, ask more to the point, add context (like mysql) in the question (not the title) when you explain what you're doing running into that problem. Have fun and good luck!